# Does a temporary shared_ptr returned by value have the counter incremented?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, return-value-optimization

I'm trying to understand how RVO works in conjunction with `shared_ptr` in this particular case.

Let's say I have this example code:

```
class A {
public:
  void action() {}
};

class Container {
public:
  shared_ptr<A> getA() { return m_a; }

private:
  shared_ptr<A> m_a;
};

Container cont{};
cont.getA()->action();
```

If I'm not wrong, in this situation the `shared_ptr` returned by `getA()` shouldn’t be copied/copy constructed because it's optimized by the compiler.
So, in the last line, the `shared_ptr` I'm calling the `action()` function on should be directly the one contained in `m_a` inside the `Container` object?

In this case, if the pointer is not copied, is the internal reference count not incremented/decremented?

And because I'm using it as an r-value, it's optimized and I can directly use it to access the pointed object without any cost, like a raw pointer?

In case it's not like that, is there a way to avoid the cost of the increment/decrement? I'm not actually keeping the `shared_ptr`, but I'm using it only for an operation on the contained object.

Or, there could be any problem with the lifetime of the contained object?

Comment: You could always just replace the `shared_ptr` with a custom-defined class that logs its instances and copy/move operations, and then you could see exactly what the compiler actually does.

Comment: a `shared_ptr` is to share ownership. If you do not want to share ownership you can return a raw pointer or reference

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number and if I want both? maybe in some situation I need to share ownership and in some other I only need to do an operation on the pointed object... I have to create to different getters?

Comment: I wouldnt worry too much about copying a shared ptr. If `action` is actually doing something then incrementing and decrementing the ref count and making the copy is likely to be insignificant for performance. Maybe it isnt, but you can only know by writing the code and measuring

Comment: getters arent the nicest thing you can do to a class design in general. Consider to write a `Container::action`. Or consider what standard containers do: They grant you direct access to their elements, they arent trying to hide them from you. What would be good for your case depends on details and what `Container` and `A`  and `action` are

Comment: Return a reference to the existing shared_ptr from `shared_ptr<A>A& getA()`. If you store it somewhere, you do a copy then. Otherwise you can just use the reference in an expression.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thanks again! 
I would like to discuss about my case because it have some limitations on the operations I can do that are not lock-free and make create a good design very difficult, but I would go out of topic here...

Comment: Just don't do `((new Container()).getA()).action()` or does `Container` outlive the parantheses?

Comment: @Sebastian thanks! 
It was one of the thing I've considered first, but as I have seen in some other answers on the topic, in that case I would loose encapsulation of the private member and it's considered bad design because someone can use it wrong and keep a reference to the pointed object without incrementing the ref count of the shared pointer

Comment: In most (not all) cases using `shared_ptr` is bad design (IMHO) - no clear ownership, no clear lifetime, possible cycles, runtime overhead, but it always depends on the requirements. There are some languages, for which shared pointers are the default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the shared_ptr returned by getA() shouldn’t be copied/copy constructed because it’s optimized by the compiler.

Yes, it will be copied. `m_a` is not a local variable so NRVO (named return value optimization) can't be done and returning it by value will indeed copy construct the returned `shared_ptr<A>`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/daT3K9zon)

Comment: thanks, I have missed the fact that it could only work with local variables, and was hoping the compiler in this case where I'm not keeping the value would have pointed directly to the member of the class as optimization.

Comment: @MixKira You're welcome! What (N)RVO does is to create the object directly at the call site, so the function needs to actually create an object. Also note that function parameters doesn't count and can't be used in NRVO.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell...

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) { std::cout << "copy\n";}
};

foo bar() {
    foo f;
    return f;
}

int main() {
    foo g;
    g = bar();
}
```

Without eliding the copy: You call the function, inside the function there is `f`, the function returns, `f` gets copied into the returned value, `f` gets destroyed, you now have `g`, a copy of `f`.

The idea of eliding the copy is: A short moment where the copy is made aside, there never more than 1 object. The only effect of not making the copy is not making the copy, ie the side effects may be skipped and the above code does not print anything.

In your case this does not apply. `m_a` is a member. It is not a function local variable. A copy must be made, because the object returned from the function is distinct from the member.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4zTMxoW9v)

[Live Demo with copy elision disabled](https://godbolt.org/z/eYn31eEYb)

Yes the temporary returned from the function is a copy. The ref count of the shared pointer is decremented at the end of the full expression.

Comment: thanks, that's more clear now... From what I had understood of the RVO it was a sort alias and so I've assumed that NRVO could also apply to returned class members as it's something the compiler know where it is in memory (related to the object) and could point to the same object in memory.

Comment: @MixKira that would be `shared_ptr<A>& getA() { return m_a; }`. Copy elision is not equivalent to returning a reference